# different timeout for different request with Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I'm using [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) to consume web services in iOS, my question is whether if it's possible to have different timeouts with Alamofire in different request to web services.

The method:

```
let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 10
```

It works well, I wonder if, in order to have two different timeouts, it's necessary to have two different instances of a Client (?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting request timeout on a per-request basis can be done by generating your own `URLRequest` values with custom `timeoutInterval`s set, or by adopting Alamofire's `URLRequestConvertible` protocol and use a more CRUD-like modeling for your APIs to produce `URLRequest`s which are performed by Alamofire. We outline such an approach in our [Advanced Usage documentation](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/AdvancedUsage.md). (Note that that document will be updated for the Alamofire 5 update soon.)